# Drupal field that get db content

Tags: views

How can I make a drupal field that gets a value from a specific database/table, it should be a select list. What I need is to have a drop down select where I can see all entries from a specific content on the drupal system. So I have content type A, and content type B. When I want to create a new content of type B I want a select box where all entries from content A are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like something you can handle pretty easily with a couple of contrib modules:

1. If you don't already have them install [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).
2. Add a View of type "Content", filtered by content type B. Call it something like "All type B content".
3. Add an "Entity Reference" display to the new View.
4. Add any sorting/filtering options and change the display field if required.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for a new view called "All type A content", and filter by content type A instead.
6. Add a new field to content type A of type "Entity Reference".
7. On the field settings page under "Entity Selection" choose *Views: filter by an entity reference view* for the mode, choose the "All type B content" View, and save the rest of the field config as normal.
8. Repeat steps 6-8 for content type B, choosing the "All type A content" View instead.

That should get you exactly what you're looking for, with the added benefit of being able to customise the results easily with Views.